# Windows - Check folder size of specific list of folders

Tags: windows-server-2003

I've been trying to establish a way to retrieve the folder size of around 5000 folders, which are contained in a folder with a total of around 15000 folders.

So for example:

```
Parent folder
   -- SubFolder
   -- SubFolder2
   -- SubFolder3
   -- SubFolder4
```

I only want to retrieve the folder size of SubFolder3 and SubFolder4 ... on a small scale this is of course trivial. When we're dealing with thousands it becomes a little more complex.

I had hoped that using something like unixkit-tiny with:

```
du -k --max-depth=1 < folderlist.txt | > foldersizes.txt
```

Would work, but that command sadly ignores the input - although the output works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to use unix tools:

```
xargs -L1 du -k --max-depth=1 <folderlist.txt >foldersizes.txt
```

Remember, unix commands tend to do one job. The job of `du` is to total file sizes. The job of `xargs` is to read a list of lines from a file.

By the way, did you really mean `--max-depth=1`, i.e., show the size of each subdirectory of the directories listed in `folderlist.txt` but don't detail their subdirectories? More commonly used options are `-s` (show the size of the listed directories, don't detail their subdirectories) and `-S` (don't include the size of subdirectories).

Comment: That's perfect. My unix command line is a little shaky so thanks for the clarification - very very helpful. You were also spot on with -s over --max-depth. Really hope this helps other folk in the future as I bashed (no pun intended) my head against this for about an hour earlier :)